# Xcode Storyboards: Can you add 'New Referencing Outlet' that connects objects in two different scenes?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

For example, uiViewControllerA has a segue to uiViewControllerB. But uiViewControllerB does not exist until the segue is performed. How can uiViewControllerA message uiViewControllerB with information that it needs? Each UIViewController is in a different 'Scene', so they can't reference each other in the usual/xib manner of connecting an IBOutlet property.

Comment: Why not pass the information during the segue in `prepareForSegue()`?

Comment: @iLikeTau:  `prepareForSegue:sender:` does not get called on my destination view controller. I guess that is the issue!!!

Comment: `prepareForSegue:sender:` is called on the source view controller but can retrieve a reference to the destination view controller from the `UIStoryboardSegue` object